# How to start rabbitMQ without package manager in Linux?

Tags: cryptography, rabbitmq, erlang

In order to prepare internal project, I'm preparing to use RabbitMQ.
But, I faced serious problem when I start to run rabbitMQ.

I have to assume environment that we couldn't use internet.
Of course, I can use RPM installer, but I prefer to build source to learn Linux.
So, I downloaded latest Erlang and RabbitMQ tar sources at this moment.

First step, I extracted erlang to custom directory such as `/square/dpa/rabbitmq/otp_src_22.1`
then moved to that directory, then I did below commands.

1. `./configure --without-termcap --with-ssl --prefix=/square/dpa/rabbitmq/erlang`
2. `make`
3. `make install`
   (Of course, I added erlang directory into PATH manually.)

Then, I extracted rabbitmq on specific directory also such as `/square/dpa/rabbitmq/rabbitmq_server-3.8.1`, then moved to `/sbin`, run './rabbitmq-server'

Unfortunately, I faced below fail log.
So how I can solve this problem? I can just expect that it was occured Erlang-Crypto is not installed.

If my expectation is correct, pls let me know how to install crypto,
and if there's another reason, pls tell me free your opinion.

-------------- log for './rabbitmq-server'

## BOOT FAILED

```
Error description:
    init:do_boot/3
    init:start_em/1
    rabbit:start_it/1 line 465
    rabbit:broker_start/1 line 341
    rabbit:start_loaded_apps/2 line 591
    app_utils:manage_applications/6 line 126
    lists:foldl/3 line 1263
    rabbit:'-handle_app_error/1-fun-0-'/3 line 714
throw:{could_not_start,credentials_obfuscation,
          {credentials_obfuscation,
              {bad_return,
                  {{credentials_obfuscation_app,start,[normal,[]]},
                   {'EXIT',
                       {undef,
                           [{crypto,strong_rand_bytes,[128],[]},
                            {credentials_obfuscation_app,start,2,
                                [{file,"src/credentials_obfuscation_app.erl"},
                                 {line,34}]},
                            {application_master,start_it_old,4,
                                [{file,"application_master.erl"},
                                 {line,277}]}]}}}}}}
Log file(s) (may contain more information):
   /square/dpa/rabbitmq/rabbitmq_server-3.8.1/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@epsqpad01.log
   /square/dpa/rabbitmq/rabbitmq_server-3.8.1/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@epsqpad01_upgrade.log

{"init terminating in do_boot",{could_not_start,credentials_obfuscation,{credentials_obfuscation,{bad_return,{{credentials_obfuscation_app,start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{undef,[{crypto,strong_rand_bytes,[128],[]},{credentials_obfuscation_app,start,2,[{file,"src/credentials_obfuscation_app.erl"},{line,34}]},{application_master,start_it_old,4,[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,277}]}]}}}}}}}
init terminating in do_boot ({could_not_start,credentials_obfuscation,{credentials_obfuscation,{bad_return,{{_},{_}}}}})
```

Comment: I'd guess that Erlang is not able to find the OpenSSL libraries at run time. Try opening an Erlang shell (with `erl`) and typing `application:start(crypto).` (including the dot) - that might give you a better error message.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I sovled this matter by your kind opinion. I have to install Open-SSL in advance, then use option '--with-ssl=PATH' (Open-SSL installed path). Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear that! You can write up your solution as an answer to your own question (using the text box below) - that way, if anyone has the same problem in the future, they can easily find how you solved it.